# URLRequest with Accept header: gets put in request body, not overrides default request header

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, firefox, header

A collaborative project has a Flash application which makes use of a sort of API (a work-in-progress, bunch of related PHP method). The API used to serve data in JSON, but now we require support for another format. There are several ways to indicate the format we expect the data to be returned in. I would like to opt in for HTTP Accept header to avoid re-inventing the wheel.

In our Flash application we have a standard bunch of code responsible for setting the Accept header.

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
var acceptHeader:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.requestHeaders.push(acceptHeader);
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
// add parameters, init a URLLoader, load the request etc.
```

This works fine on Internet Explorer and Chrome / Chromium - web consoles show the header altered as expected (lowercasing them though). But Firefox / Iceweasel exhibit strange behaviour. According to the headers section in the built-in inspector, the standard header gets passed only:

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

Running Live HTTP headers (FF extension) and catching the requests from the application yields stranger results (unimportant headers omitted, paths changed etc) :

```
POST /path-to-script.phtml?id=1 HTTP/1.1
Host: devserver.com
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
<...>
    Referer: http://devserver.com/path-to-flash.swf
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Accept: application/json

    <POST payload>
```

Actual payload is a stub as `URLRequest` disallows changing headers for the `GET` method. The payload and the three last headers are also indented for some reason, making them part of a request body rather than request headers.

Skimming through POST requests in Firefox - actually in Iceweasel 9.01 on Debian, if that matters, same seen in FF10 on Win7 - reveals other cases with the same symptoms. Namely on `community.adobe.com`, but the requests from SWF there are accompanied both by the Accept header and the POST parameter indicating the desired JSON format.

So, there are two questions:

1. Is it possible to really overwrite the default HTTP header from an SWF opened via Firefox? Are we just anything wrong?
2. Is it a better practice to reuse this HTTP instrument or maybe we need to stick with an additional parameter and start rewriting the URLs into stuff like `/api/someObject.<json|xml>/123`?

Comment: As I didn't find a good way to alleviate this problem, I had to kinda bypass it by an ugly hack: `/api/<method_name>.<accept_format>/` gets mod_rewritten and passed to a 'compatibility connector' that emulates http accept header, moves input data from `POST` to whatever it should be (i.e. into `GET` for read-methods) and just passes execution to the method in question. That way I have both Flash running via this and JS AJAX requests via jQuery in normal mode.

Answer (score 0):

```
var acceptHeader:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
```

this works for us. Thank you